# Documents don't show up in Chroma database after adding them

Tags: python, langchain, chromadb

When I'm trying to add texts to a [chromadb database](https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/vectorstores/langchain.vectorstores.chroma.Chroma.html) I do get ID:s that are supposed to have been added to the database, but when I later check for them they are not there.

```
# Load database from persist_directory.
vectordb = Chroma(
    persist_directory=persist_directory, embedding_function=embedding
)
# Add new documents.
vectordb.add_texts(text_splitted, metadatas)
```

The database was created with

```
embedding = HuggingFaceEmbeddings()
vectordb = Chroma.from_texts(
            texts=texts_splitted,
            metadatas=metadatas,
            embedding=embedding,
            persist_directory=persist_directory,
        )
vectordb.persist()
```

I have tried to call [vectordb.persist()](https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/vectorstores/langchain.vectorstores.chroma.Chroma.html#langchain.vectorstores.chroma.Chroma.persist) after adding new documents but same result. Do I need to do something else? And if it's not possible to add documents to an already created database and have them saved there, is there a way of creating a new database from the old + the new documents?

Comment: refer - https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/chromadb-tutorial-step-by-step-guide